# NHibernate queryover how to apply date isbetween without including the from and todate

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to write NHibernate queryover to select all records which has been deleted between two dates. I am using IsBetween().And(). But how do i write if i dont want to include both the fromdate and todate?

Here is my query:

```
public IEnumerable<DeletedRecord> Search(
    DateTime deletedFrom,
    DateTime deletedTo
    )
{
    DeletedRecord delAlias = null;
    var query = Session.QueryOver(() => delAlias);
    query.Where(() => delAlias.DeletedDate.IsBetween(deletedFrom).And(deletedTo));

    return query.Future<DeletedRecord>();
}
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve so that i can bring all records after the deletedFrom date and before the deletedTo date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just construct your date in 2 steps:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver(() => delAlias);

if(youNeedFromDate) //first step
   query = query.Where(() => delAlias.DeletedDate >= deletedFrom);
if(youNeedToDate) //second step
   query = query.Where(() => delAlias.DeletedDate <= deletedTo);
```

`youNeedFromDate` and `youNeedToDate` are `bool` variables that you can pass to your function or it could be different condition upon your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Such cases happen quite often .  defining extension method helps a lot. see below

```
    public static IQueryOver<T, T> WhereIf<T>(this IQueryOver<T, T> query,bool condition, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class
    {            
        if (condition)
        {
            query = query.And(expression);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Using the above you can chain you conditions and only it will only include the where condition if the first arg evaluates to true.

```
 var query= Session.QueryOver<DeletedRecord>()
      .WhereIf(filterByFrom,d=>d.DeletedDate>=fromDate)
      .WhereIf(filterByTo,d=>d.DeletedDate<=toDate);
```